# Copy object attribute values to another object which has, but less of the same attributes

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Consider I have Object A:

```
const ObjectA = {
    attribute1: "text",
    attribute2: "text",
}
```

And Object B

```
const ObjectB = {
    attribute1: "tex2t",
    attribute2: "text2",
    attribute3: "text2"
}
```

Is it possible to give ObjectA attributes all the values of Object B?

I understand that saying:

```
ObjectA = ObjectB
```

Would make ObjectA handle the extra attribute3, but this is undesirable for me.

How do I assign the existing attributes of ObjectB to ObjectA's attributes, but without adding the attributes that ObjectA doesn't have i.e attribute3. Is it possible without a looping operation?

Thanks

Comment: You'll need a loop for this, there's no native method.

Comment: What is your expected output like?

Comment: Expected output would be that ObjectA = { attribute1: "tex2t", attribute2: "text2"}

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a loop. Here's an example with a `.forEach()`, though there's multiple other valid approaches as well.

```js
const objectA = {
    attribute1: "text",
    attribute2: "text",
};
const objectB = {
    attribute1: "tex2t",
    attribute2: "text2",
    attribute3: "text2"
};

Object.keys(objectB).forEach(key => {
  if(objectA.hasOwnProperty(key)) objectA[key] = objectB[key];
});

console.log(objectA);
```